# Smoother transition from one UIView to another UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I have a `UIViewController` which has multiple subviews. Each subview is a `UIView` subclass, and I want to switch between views by tapping the toolbar buttons. I did this by using the animation blocks:

Example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight 
                 animations:^{
                         [StoreView removeFromSuperview];
                         [self.view addSubview:HomeView]; 
                     }
                 completion:NULL];
```

Everything is working fine actually. The problem is the transition is not really smooth. For example, the `HomeView` has five buttons scattered (as part of the design), and whenever I switch from one view to `HomeView`, these buttons will come from a corner and rearrange itself after the transition, which is not exactly beautiful to look at.

So how will I make these buttons stay in place?

Comment: You'd probably get some answers if you should show a screenshot or mockup of what you're trying to achieve and a picture of what you're getting now.

Comment: I can't quite tell what your problem is... I don't think there's enough info in your question right now. Have you tried using 
        `[UIView transitionFromView:HomeView toView:StoreView duration:0.75 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:nil];`? This would replace your current animation block.

Comment: Also, it depends on what contains in `StoreView`. Is it just a plain view? Does it contain data from the web? Does it contain High-res images? The solution varies by the problem.

Comment: The `StoreView` is not the problem. It shows up perfectly. No delays whatsoever. `HomeView` is the only one that I'm concerned about. `HomeView` contains custom `UIButtons` with images in it. Basically, these UIButtons will redirect me to the other views. These other views doesn't really contain any buttons except for the Home Button, so there is no problem when I animate from `HomeView` to another view. As for the screenshot, I will be happy to provide but it is hard for me to capture one since it happens really fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing animations with complex subviews you can sometimes get undesirable results as you are experiencing.  Not only can some oddities appear, but they are sometimes costly depending on the complexity of the view structure.  One suggestion I would make is instead of animating the complex views themselves, you could render the views to a graphics context and animate the resulting image in a `UIImageView`, using sleight-of-hand to make it appear that you are animating the view hierarchy.  In this effect, you avoid doing what amounts to a complex transform on the `HomeView` and `StoreView` and instead do simple flip with `UIImageView` instances.  Consider the following example code:

```
UIImageView *storeImage = //  pointer to the image rendered to a graphics context
UIImageView *homeImage =  //  pointer to the image rendered to a graphics context

[self.view addSubview:storeImage];
[storeView removeFromSuperview];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight 
                 animations:^{
                         [storeImage removeFromSuperview];
                         [self.view addSubview:homeImage]; 
                     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self.view addSubview:homeView];
                     [homeImage removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I will try this and see if it will work.

Comment: For future reference, the best way to get snapshots on iOS 7 is using `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`.